# Cheerio itemprop attribute content selection

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I am using Cheerio in nodejs to select text from a URL where an element contains the attribute itemprop="name".

At the moment I need to know the parent element in order to read the attribute and associated text. See below as an example.

However, what I would like to do is insert a wildcard for the Element. eg. H2, so I can select any attribute with name="itemprop". Is this possible?

```
var $ = cheerio.load(body);
var domElem = $("h2[itemprop = 'name']").get(0);
var content = $(domElem).text().trim();
ogTitle = content;
console.log(content);
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you can do the following as a wilcard:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(body);
var domElem = $("*[itemprop = 'name']").get(0);
var content = $(domElem).text().trim();
ogTitle = content;
console.log(content);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following also worked for me:

Html Code:

```
<a href="/someLine" itemscope="" itemprop="author" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <span itemprop="name">Jane Author</span>
</a>
```

Used this to get Jane Author:

```
author = $("*[itemprop = 'author']").text();  
// Jane Author
```